# How to build angular project to put the index.html file out of the build directory?

Tags: angular

In my angular project I have index.html file inside the "app" directory. But I need to build my project in a way that I can bring it out of the app folder. I use this command to build the project and everything works correctly:

```
node --max_old_space_size=8192 node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --base-href=/app/ --prod
```

and the output is like this:
[image]

But I want this output:
[image]

Comment: Why you wanna do that? What is your use case. Changing the index.html path also means changing the script path location also in Index.html file

Comment: In your package.json you could just define your own command in scripts section does 2 things: first build your project as stated above and then move index.html afterwards.

Comment: Thr relative addresses of build output need that the index.html be in the same directory. I need to build it in the way that index.html a directory upper

Comment: When I try to change the URLs manually it does not work because the relative addresses are made dynamically in runtime javascript  library

Answer (score -2):

to put all files in a custom folder you need to add those line in angular.json file

```
"build": {
      ...
      "options": {
        "outputPath": "dist/new_app",
        "deployUrl": "new_app/",
```

the deploy url will let you put you index.html file in another place by moving it
example in you package.json file, you can add in script a new command and run it after the build

```
"postbuild": "mv ./dist/new_app/index.html ./dist",
```

Comment: OP clearly stated the they want only the base html document in a nonstandard location.

Comment: The postbuild script is what was required for me to place the file where i needed it

Comment: "deployUrl" is now deprecated. This would work for angular < 14